# Dissecting a python puzzle forloop solution

Tags: python, for-loop, encryption

For a specific puzzle online I had to grab (using python) every lowercase letter surrounded by three uppercase letters on both sides. So for example in `'WExWQPoKLGnnNMOkPPOQ'`, the letters `ok` should be printed out. Despite finding a haphazard solution myself, a specific solution by another participant grabbed my attention:

```
import string
word = ""
for i in range(len(code) - 8):
 if [c for c in code[i:i+9] if c in string.lowercase] == [code[i], code[i+4], code[i+8]]:
     word += code[i+4]
```

I was wondering if someone could break down this code for me. I have some specific questions but a rundown would be great too:

- why does `code[i:i+9]` not produce a `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`?
- what does `string.lowercase` do in this instance?
- why does `code[i:i+9]` grab nine characters instead of seven(six uppercase and the lowercase in the middle)?
- why bother checking if `code[i+8]` evaluates to true if `[i+4]`(the lowercase letter that satisfies the requirement's puzzle) is 4 spaces to the left, especially since only three characters to the right or left of the 'correct' letter are relevant?

The puzzle itself can be found here: http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/equality.html (inspect the source code)

Comment: wow that's a spooky puzzle

Comment: Why is the output for your example `ok` instead of `k`?

Comment: Because of human error, fixed now!

Comment: Ok and now why isn't it `o`? That's what that code produces.

Comment: @njzk2 Given that that code does get you the correct answer to get to the next level, I'd say it does work.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it does indeed. The OP mis-interpreted the question.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm honestly confused as to why the code would not work in this case but does in the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does code[i:i+9] not produce a TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly?

Why would it? It is simply a slice notation, `i` is an int, `code` is a string.

> what does string.lowercase do in this instance?

It is a constant that contains all lower case letters. (It does not exist any longer in Python 3, as it is locale dependant.)

> why does code[i:i+9] grab nine characters instead of seven(six uppercase and the lowercase in the middle)?

According to the actual description of the problem, the lowercase must be *"surrounded by EXACTLY three"* uppercase letters. So you can't just check the 7, you need all the 9.

> why bother checking if code[i+8] evaluates to true if [i+4](the lowercase letter that satisfies the requirement's puzzle) is 4 spaces to the left, especially since only three characters to the right or left of the 'correct' letter are relevant?

Likewise, it is not only the 3 characters that are relevant, it is the 4. The fourth needs to be a lowercase.

What this code does it that it filters the 9-letter slice to keep only the lowercase, and checks if that is exactly the 1st, 5th and last letters.

Comment: Ah I see now why you need nine, I've been staring at my solution and feeling guilty about `import re` this whole time. **EXACTLY** couldn't be bold enough for me haha.

why then does my code produce a type error `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` on line 4:

Comment: you use a different for loop. `for i in range(len(code))` enumerates the indices, but `for i in code` enumerates the characters of `code`. but you already knew that, since you test `i.islower()`.

Comment: to access both the value and the index, use enumerate, like this: https://repl.it/Dk1B

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration, `code[i:i+9]` extracts a sequence of 9 consecutive letters in the `code`string.  For example, the first time `WExWQPoKL`.  The next iteration will give `ExWQPoKLG`.

At each of there iterations, out of these 9 letters, positions 1,2,3 and 5,6,7 should be uppercase letters, therefore not appear on the result of `[c for c in code[i:i+9] if c in string.lowercase]`.  Only positions 0,4, and 8 (remember positions in python start at 0).  If it is the case, that means that character at position 4 (middle) is surrounded by 3 uppercase letters on the left (1,2,3) and on the right (5,6,7).

That means that if the string `code`is "ABCdEFG", the letter "d" will not be returned by the code you posted.  I would change it to:

```
import string
code ="ABCdEFGhIJK"
word = []
for i in range(len(code) - 6):
  if [c for c in code[i:i+7] if c in string.lowercase] == [code[i+3]]:
     word += code[i+3]

print word
print code
```

This prints (python2)

```
['d', 'h']
ABCdEFGhIJK
```